# php inside name of $_POST

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a form, and on submit I want it to run a query. Although there is going to be multiple forms and multiple queries. [Because this will be inside a while loop].

```
if ($_POST['Test']) {
 //Query here
}

<form name="Test" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="Test" value="Click here"/>
</form>
```

So if I have it like this, it will work. Although as its in a while loop, depending on how many there is on the page, it won't work individually.

I've tried adding variables to the name of the input and $_POST such as how it is Test".$id." But it doesn't seem to work. This is my full code below.

```
if ($_POST['Test'.$id.'']) {
 //Query here
}

<form name="Test'.$id.'" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="Test'.$id.'" value="Click here"/>
</form>
```

How would I be able to do this?

Thanks

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['test'])){
//if you have clicked on test.
}`

Comment: By using isset, does that make each individual?

Comment: Explain what you want to achieve. Just creating a lot of forms is redundant.

Comment: `<form method="post">
         <input type="hidden" name="id" value="your id"/>
        <input type="submit" name="Test" value="Click here"/>
</form>
<form method="post">
         <input type="hidden" name="id" value="your id 2"/>
        <input type="submit" name="form2" value="Click here"/>
</form>

 
if(isset($_POST['test'])){ //if you have clicked on first form }
if(isset($_POST['form2'])){ //if you have clicked on second form }`

Comment: it will check with the name you assign to the submit input. Naming form is not a valid way to deal with this

Comment: @u_mulder I'm using it in a while loop. So its grabbing multiple things from the database then showing. Inside the loop where it shows certain things, I want it to have a form.

Comment: It is totally unclear what you are trying and why. You should explain the scenario or your question is likely to be closed soon. Give a real world example from your code, not only "test" and "query here".

Comment: Okay, Ill try to explain as good as I possibly can. I'm creating something where it grabs information from my database. A query is run, and then I'm using while ($Post = mysql_fetch_assoc($getPost)){ // THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE FORM AND SUBMIT } So thats obviously going to bring up as many fields as it can find in my database. For each, I want it to have a form. But I need the forms to somehow be different so when I submit, it submits the one inside the current loop.

Comment: Since your project is top secret, you won't get appropriate answers. This question/answers are not very useful to the public.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I got my answer below. But my project is not top secret, its just that theres not much to explain. Obviously others have been able to understand what I want without needing to know what I am developing. I don't know why you'd need anything different to me mentioning test and "query here", because its the exact same just obviously a different name and a query. If you can't understand that, then don't try to answer. Because others have been able to easily. But thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you need this, but try this to make as you want.

```
if ($_POST['Test'.$id]) {
 //Query here
}

<form name="Test<?php echo $id;?>" method="post" action="">
        <input type="submit" name="Test<?php echo $id;?>" value="Click here"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing what you do now with submit buttons named differently is wrong. You never know how many buttons will you have and what to do next.

I don't know what are all your multiple forms are for, but I suppose they are for working with some similar items, I suppose with some hypothetical database records. In this case you should do this.

Generate as many forms as you need with **same** `input` names. For example, if you want to update some user name in a list, you can do:

```
<form name="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="1" />
    <input type="text" name="username" value="John" />
    <input type="submit" name="Test" value="Click here"/>
</form>
<form name="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="2" />
    <input type="text" name="username" value="Max" />
    <input type="submit" name="Test" value="Click here"/>
</form>
<form name="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="3" />
    <input type="text" name="username" value="Sam" />
    <input type="submit" name="Test" value="Click here"/>
</form>
```

See, all forms has same inputs with same names. So, whichever form you submit - you will always have `$_POST` as array with **3** keys:

```
userid
username
Test
```

After that you just use **one** handler for all **similar** forms:

```
if (isset($_POST['Test'])) {
    echo $_POST['userid'],', ',$_POST['username'];
    // do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP as a template language. Write HTML and include short  tags.

You can handle most things in one form. Input names like "name[id]" will result in a PHP array `$_POST['name'] = [ 'id' => 'some_value']`. Multiple submit buttons can be archieved by the `<button>` tag which has a `name`, a `value` not displayed and inner HTML, that is displayed.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['which_button']))
  echo "Button $_POST[which_button] has been pressed.";

if(isset($_POST['some_choice']))
  var_dump($_POST['some_choice']);

$some_field = isset($_POST['some_field']) ? $_POST['some_field'] : '';

$some_data_from_db = 'DUMMY DATA';
?>

<form method="post">
  <input name="some_field" type="text" value="<?php echo $some_field?>">
  <input name="some_data_from_db" type="text" value="<?php echo $some_data_from_db?>">

  <input type="checkbox" name="some_choice[a]">a
  <input type="checkbox" name="some_choice[b]">b
  <input type="checkbox" name="some_choice[c]">c

  <button name="which_button" value="1">Button 1</button>
  <button name="which_button" value="2">Button 2</button>
  <button name="which_button" value="3">Button 3</button>
</form>
```